# (UE4 Assimp) Issues loading mtl texture at runtime

Tags: c++, runtime, textures, unreal-engine4, assimp

I'm using Assimp to import 3d Obj at runtime with Unreal Engine.
I try to import textures thanks to the mtl file, I can get the name texture file, but my problem is, how to use it to import the texture in a UTexture2D and put it in a MID ?

```
if (scene->HasMaterials())
    {
        for (unsigned int m = 0; m < scene->mNumMaterials; ++m)
        {
            aiMaterial* material = scene->mMaterials[m];
            aiString materialName;
            aiReturn ret;

            ret = material->Get(AI_MATKEY_NAME, materialName);
            if (ret != AI_SUCCESS) materialName = "";

            //Diffuse maps
            int numTextures = material->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE);
            aiString textureName;

            if (numTextures > 0)
            {
               
                ret = material->Get(AI_MATKEY_TEXTURE(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0), textureName);

                std::string textureType = "diffuse_";
                std::string textureFileName = textureType + textureName.data;//Name Texture file 
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I can answer your question to some extent based on what you've provided.

From what I understand in your question is that you have access to the filename (this has to be the full path) that holds your texture and want to import it as a UTexture2D. I haven't worked with importing in C++ before, but I'm assuming it's just as simple to do as in blueprints. In blueprints there's an existing node that does exactly that. Take a look: [Import File as Texture 2D](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Rendering/ImportFileasTexture2D/index.html)

Now you have to remember that importing it as such will not actually create a permanent material for you that you can reference even after resetting your game. This will just import it at runtime for the duration of your game, and delete all references to it after you exit game.

As for putting it in an MID, I'm unsure what an MID is. Do you mean DMI (Dynamic Material Instance)? If not, please clarify and hopefully I'll be of further help. If you do mean DMI, then that's also quite simple, although unfortunately I haven't worked with that in C++ either. However I'll run you through the blueprint and hopefully you can interpret that in C++ yourself.

To create a DMI, you need to have already created a material that holds the parameters that you want to then change when creating the DMI. For a very basic example, here's one I'll use for the purpose of demonstration: [image: TestMaterial] As you can see, I've created a material with a TextureObjectParameter. Name this parameter what you wish, it's important to give it a relevant name as this is what you will refer to when modifying your DMI (in this example case I'm naming it "color").

Next, when you want to create a DMI of this material, this is how it's done in blueprints: [image] In this picture, just for your example, I import my texture first, then I create a DMI of class TestMaterial, and I modify whichever parameter that I have created in the original material class to what I want it to be (in this example case the parameter to change is "color" and I want it to be changed to the texture I just imported). You can modify as many parameters as you want, but remember these parameters have to exist in the first place in your original material class. Remember though, DMIs also exist just in runtime and all references to them will be deleted after you exit your game, so use them carefully!

I really hope I understood your question properly and I'm very sorry for not being able to provide actual C++ help. Best of luck going forward with your game development though!